# Incorrect encoding of the Cyrillic's characters by BindValue

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, pdo, symfony, php-7

I have DB on MS SQL 2008 R2
I install follow software:

1. Ubuntu 16

   1. Apache 2
   2. PHP 7
   3. Symfony 3.0 (with leaseweb/doctrine-pdo-dblib)
2. Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1

   1. MS SQL Server 2008 R2 SP3 (with Cyrillic_General_CI_AS - I can't change the collation)

In my project, there is controller which has follow code

```php
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$connection = $em->getConnection();
$sql="
select
    isnull(ID,'') as 'id'
    ,isnull(SNAME,'') as 'sname'
    ,isnull(FNAME,'') as 'fname'
from TBL1
where SNAMElike '%'+:sname+'%' ";

$sql =  iconv('UTF-8','Windows-1251', $sql);
$statement = $connection->prepare($sql);
$statement->bindValue(':sname', iconv('UTF-8', 'Windows-1251', $request->request->get('sname')), 'text');
$statement->execute();
```

In SQL Server Profiler I watch the string `0xc8e2e0edeee2` instead of `Агеев`. As you can see the codes is come from UTF8.

if I don't use the code page conversion,

```php
$statement->bindValue(':sname', $request->request->get('sname'), 'text');
```

I see the string `0xd098d0b2d0b0d0bdd0bed0b2` in  SQL Server Profiler.

If I don't use `BindValue` and put the variable into SQL like it's shown below

```php
$sname = $request->request->get('sname');
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$connection = $em->getConnection();
$sql="
select
    isnull(ID,'') as 'id'
    ,isnull(SNAME,'') as 'sname'
    ,isnull(FNAME,'') as 'fname'
from TBL1
where SNAMElike '%'+'".$sname."'+'%' ";

$sql =  iconv('UTF-8','Windows-1251', $sql);
$statement = $connection->prepare($sql);
$statement->execute();
```

I watch correct string  `Иванов` in SQL Server Profiler.

---

If the variable containts a string which has only latin charasters then there areb't any problem.

I send the string `Ivanov` and I watch the string `Ivanov`.

---

**What is the problem?**

Comment: Have you specified the correct encoding for the connection?

Comment: @Andrea What do you mean exactly?

1. The encoding in `config.yml`
2. The encoding of PHP/Symfony files
3. The encoding of POST request

Comment: the encoding setting for the database connection. I'm not sure where it's configured when using Doctrine, but you should be able to find out in the documentation.

Comment: @Andrea I did it, but it didn't help me

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in quoter function that called for each string parameter `dblib_handle_quoter` in `ext\pdo_dblib\dblib_driver.c`. It will convert any string containing character with codes outside of `32 > char > 127` range into binary string.

So if `Агеев` is not converted to 'Windows-1251' it becomes `0xd098d0b2d0b0d0bdd0bed0b2` - a UTF-8 representation converted to binary string (something like `РРІР°РЅРѕРІ`).

SQL Server then implicitly converts this binary value to string using:

- single-byte conversion (with `CP1251` code page in your case i guess), if expected data type is `char` or `varchar`. Here you need to convert parameters to `Windows-1251`.
- unicode conversion, if expected data type is `nchar` or `nvarchar`. Here you need to convert parameters to `UCS-2LE`.

That's why there is no other choice (at least for now) than to use `iconv` for parameters.

PS If you set connection charset right, you shouldn't need to convert `$sql` as it should be done by dblib.

I use `freetds-1.00.13` with `PHP7` as `pdo-dblib` like this (data types is `varchar`):

```
function pdo_params(...$params){
  foreach ($params as &$v){
    $v = iconv('UTF-8','Windows-1251', $v);
  }
  unset($v);
  return $params;
}

$dsn = 'dblib:dbname=DataBase;host=sql.server.host.name';

<...>

$dbh = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password,array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION));
$stmt = $dbh->prepare('INSERT INTO table (a,b) VALUES (?,?)');
$stmt->execute(pdo_params("Test",$msg));
```